# data not showing in realtime database but showing on firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
package com.example.trial_myapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button b1,b2;
    private Uri imageuri;
    FirebaseAuth auth;


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK&&requestCode==1&&data.getData()!=null)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"onactivity wala",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            imageuri = data.getData();
            chosefile(imageuri);
        }
    }

    private void chosefile(Uri imageuri) {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"choose file wala",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("uploading");
        pd.show();
        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("uploads").child(System.currentTimeMillis()+"."+getFileExtension(imageuri));
        storageReference.putFile(imageuri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"uploaded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("uploads").push().setValue(uri.toString())
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete( Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful())
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"failure",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        String k = uri.toString();
                        Log.d("msg",k);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,k,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri imageuri) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"extension wala",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(imageuri));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        b1 = findViewById(R.id.add_image);
        b2 = findViewById(R.id.show_image);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("cc").setValue("hello");
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"intent wala",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent( MainActivity.this,Showimages.class));
            }
        });


    }


}
```

i am getting the link to the image in Log.d and the toast

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"uploaded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

AND

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,k,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

are both shown but url is not saved in realtime database...saw some ques on stackoverflow but didn't found answer
the image is getting saved in firebase storage.

if i add this

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("cc").setValue("hello");
```

on b1.setonclick...
then also it is not added in realtime database.

On same browser for another app data is being added to both realtime db and storage, the code is similar in both apps.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the setValue() method, to see if something's wrong?

Comment: tried it now sir @AlexMamo and yes there might be the problem as "sucess" and "failure" both are not showed as toast , added it to code.

Comment: Where is your database located?

Comment: i am not sure what u mean by location sir @AlexMamo..it shows "Database location: Singapore (asia-southeast1)" on realtime database page

Comment: sir any thing @AlexMamo

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve this.

Comment: pls can you share the code we will use here @AlexMamo..i am very confused here ,i can't take instance of child "uploads". it shows error.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the location to the getInstance() method?